# About embedded submanifolds and its definitions

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I have a big problem understanding the following theorem

**Theorem** Let M, N be k-manifolds, and $f:M\to N$ an embedding. Then $f(M)$ is a submanifol of $N$.

I have seen the proof in severals books, however it is not clear what they did. So, I will
write my attemp.

Firts, I will write some definitions

**Sub Manifold** Let $X$ be a manifold of dimension n. Let $A\subset X$. We say that $A$ is a submanifold if
$\forall x\in M$, $\exists U_x \subset X$, $V_0\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a diffeomorphism $g:U_x \to V_0$
such that $g(U_x\cap M)=V_0\cap (\mathbb{R}\cap\times  \{0\})$.

In an equivalent way, we could say that $A$ is a submanifold if there is a chart $(U,\psi)$ such that 
$\psi(A\cap X)$ is a sub manifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, with these definitions I will try to prove my theorem:
**draft of the prove**

Let $y\in f(M)$. Let $U_y\subset N$ be a open neighborhood and $(U,\psi)$ be a chart of $y$. We have that there exist $x\in M$ such that $f(x)=y$. Also, we consider $(V, \phi)$ a chart of $x$.

As $f$ is an homeomorphism, we have that $f(V)$ is open respect to the induced topology of $f(M)$, so 
we could have
\begin{equation}
f(V)=f(M)\cap U.
\end{equation}

So if instead of $f$ we take $\psi^{-1} \circ f \circ \phi$
\begin{equation}
\psi^{-1} \circ f \circ \phi(V)=\psi^{-1} \circ f \circ \phi (M)\cap U.
\end{equation}

can I assure that?, What I am missing, and I read that with the final line we can conclude the proof
but I don't know how. 
Thanks for your time.

Edit

I think this is the answer to my question 
[Two definitions of embedded submanifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079757/two-definitions-of-embedded-submanifold)

Comment: What is your definition of embedding ?

Comment: it means that $f$ is an inmersion and also $M$ is homeomorphic to $f(M)$

Comment: So the hypotheses $M \approx f(M)$ is not needed then.

Comment: yes that's true. I wll edit

Comment: The theorem easier to prove if you use another definition of submanifold.

Comment: What is that definition?

Comment: Look at the second paragraph of $\textbf{Immersed Submanifold}$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold).